# Ubuntu Horizontal Scroll sendo interpretado como botão direito no Netbeans, Astah

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

No Ubuntu podemos habilitar o horizontal scroll no dconf Editor.

Ao usá-lo, no Netbeans e em alguns outros programas, como o Astah, o horizontal scroll não funciona, sendo interpretado como um clique do botão direito do mouse.

Como fazer o horizontal scroll funcionar nesses programas?

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa que eu encontrei foi criar um script para habilitar/desabilitar o horizontal scroll, mas o que me interessa mesmo que ainda não sei é como fazer funcionar.

Criei outra pergunta sobre o script para habilitar desabilitar: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10986/script-para-habilitar-desabilitar-horizontal-scroll-no-ubuntu)