# Script para habilitar/desabilitar horizontal scroll no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

Alguns programas não funcionam bem com o horizontal scroll no Ubuntu, como o Netbeans e o Astah ([Pergunta no tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10985/ubuntu-horizontal-scroll-sendo-interpretado-como-botao-direito-no-netbeans-asta)).

Uma alternativa é habilitar/desabilitar o horizontal scroll através de um script.

Answer (score 1):

A alternativa que encontrei para o horizontal scroll não atrapalhar enquanto uso esses programas é um script para habilitar/desabilitar.

Crie o arquivo **/usr/local/bin/hs_disable**

```
DEVICE_NAME='ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
PROP_NAME='Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling'

xinput set-int-prop "$DEVICE_NAME" "$PROP_NAME" 8 1 0
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
  notify-send "Script" "Horizontal Scrolling Disabled" -i /usr/share/pixmaps/touchpad_disabled.png -t 5000
else
  notify-send "Script" "Error disabling horizontal scroll." -i /usr/share/pixmaps/Cancel-icon.png -t 5000
fi
```

Crie o arquivo **/usr/local/bin/hs_enable**

```
DEVICE_NAME='ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
PROP_NAME='Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling'

xinput set-int-prop "$DEVICE_NAME" "$PROP_NAME" 8 1 1
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
  notify-send "Script" "Horizontal Scrolling Enabled" -i /usr/share/pixmaps/touchpad.png -t 5000
else
  notify-send "Script" "Error enabling horizontal scroll." -i /usr/share/pixmaps/Cancel-icon.png -t 5000
fi
```

Execute **chmod +x** nos dois arquivos para permitir a execução